# Why is my CSS not applying to my react component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react button. I use this react button throughout my website with no issues, besides in one section. I have two buttons and I want them to have better animation than simple fade in and fade out. I have gone and written code for more intense animation, but--much to my chagrin--the css doesn't change/work. Attached below are my global styles, HeroStyles, and Hero.js. Any idea why? am I inadvertently inheriting something? Any comments on how my code looks too?

GlobalStyles.js

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
`;

export const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
`;
export const MainHeading = styled.h1`
    font-size: clamp(2.3rem, 6vw, 4.5rem);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    color: ${({ inverse }) => (inverse ? '$403ae3' : '#fff')};
    width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-align: center;
`;

export const Heading = styled.h2`
    font-size: clamp(1.3rem, 13vw, 3.1rem);
    margin: ${({ margin }) => (margin ? margin : '')};
    margin-bottom: ${({ mb }) => (mb ? mb : '')};
    margin-top: ${({ mt }) => (mt ? mt : '')};
    color: ${({ inverse }) => (inverse ? '$403ae3' : '#fff')};
    letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
    line-height: 1.06;
    text-align: center;
    width: ${({ width }) => (width ? width : '100%')};
`;
export const TextWrapper = styled.span`
    color: ${({ color }) => (color ? color : '')};
    font-size: ${({ size }) => (size ? size : '')};
    font-weight: ${({ weight }) => (weight ? weight : '')};
    letter-spacing: ${({ spacing }) => (spacing ? spacing : '')};
    padding: ${({ padding }) => (padding ? padding : '')};
    margin: ${({ margin }) => (margin ? margin : '')};
    margin-bottom: ${({ mb }) => (mb ? mb : '')};
    margin-top: ${({ mt }) => (mt ? mt : '')};
`;
export const Section = styled.section`
    padding: ${({ padding }) => (padding ? padding : '140px 0')};
    margin: ${({ margin }) => (margin ? margin : '')};
    background: ${({ inverse }) => (inverse ? 'white' : '#071c2f')};
    position: ${({ position }) => (position ? position : '')};
    width: ${({ width }) => (width ? width : 'auto')};
    min-width: ${({ minWidth }) => (minWidth ? minWidth : 'auto')};
    max-width: ${({ maxWidth }) => (maxWidth ? maxWidth : 'auto')};
    height: ${({ height }) => (height ? height : 'auto')};
    max-height: ${({ maxHeight }) => (maxHeight ? maxHeight : 'auto')};
    min-height: ${({ minHeight }) => (minHeight ? minHeight : 'auto')};
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        padding: ${({ smPadding }) => (smPadding ? smPadding : '70px 0')};
    }
`;

export const Row = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ${({ justify }) => (justify ? justify : '')};
    align-items: ${({ align }) => (align ? align : '')};
    gap: ${({ gap }) => (gap ? gap : '')};
    padding: ${({ padding }) => (padding ? padding : '')};
    margin: ${({ margin }) => (margin ? margin : '')};
    position: ${({ position }) => (position ? position : '')};
    width: ${({ width }) => (width ? width : 'auto')};
    min-width: ${({ minWidth }) => (minWidth ? minWidth : 'auto')};
    max-width: ${({ maxWidth }) => (maxWidth ? maxWidth : 'auto')};
    height: ${({ height }) => (height ? height : 'auto')};
    max-height: ${({ maxHeight }) => (maxHeight ? maxHeight : 'auto')};
    min-height: ${({ minHeight }) => (minHeight ? minHeight : 'auto')};
    flex-wrap: ${({ wrap }) => (wrap ? wrap : '')};
`;

export const Column = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: ${({ justify }) => (justify ? justify : '')};
    align-items: ${({ align }) => (align ? align : '')};
    gap: ${({ gap }) => (gap ? gap : '')};
    padding: ${({ padding }) => (padding ? padding : '')};
    margin: ${({ margin }) => (margin ? margin : '')};
    position: ${({ position }) => (position ? position : '')};
    width: ${({ width }) => (width ? width : 'auto')};
    min-width: ${({ minWidth }) => (minWidth ? minWidth : 'auto')};
    max-width: ${({ maxWidth }) => (maxWidth ? maxWidth : 'auto')};
    height: ${({ height }) => (height ? height : 'auto')};
    max-height: ${({ maxHeight }) => (maxHeight ? maxHeight : 'auto')};
    min-height: ${({ minHeight }) => (minHeight ? minHeight : 'auto')};
`;

export const Button = styled.button`
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    &:before {
        background: #fff;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: -1;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    }
    &:hover:before {
        height: 500%;
    }
    &:hover {
        color: black;
    }
`;

export default GlobalStyle;
```

HeroStyles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button, MainHeading } from '../../globalStyles';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export const HeroSection = styled.section`
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: clamp(70px, 25vh, 220px);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(196, 78%, 62%, 1) 0%, hsla(201, 66%, 53%, 1) 27%, hsla(207, 74%, 47%, 1) 51%, hsla(213, 79%, 43%, 1) 76%, hsla(221, 95%, 42%, 1) 100%);    
`;

export const HeroHeading = styled(MainHeading)`
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
`;

export const HeroText = styled.p`
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    font-size: clamp(0.9rem, 2vw, 1.3rem);
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #fff;
`;

export const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    gap: clamp(1.5rem, 2.5vw, 5rem);
`;

export const HeroButton1 = styled(Button)`
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 2.75vw, 1.75rem);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
    text-decoration:none;
    background: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: none;
    position: realtive;
    &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
        color: white;
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    }
`;

// export const HeroButton1 = styled(Button)`
//  position: relative;
//  margin: 0 15px;
//  padding: 10px 30px;
//  color: white;
//  text-decoration: none;
//  text-transform: uppercase;
//  font-size: 20px;
//  &:before {
//      content: '';
//      position: absolute;
//      top: 0;
//      left: 0;
//      width: 10px;
//      height: 10px;
//      border-top: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
//      border-left: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
//      transition: 0.5s; 
//  }
//  &:hover:before {
//      width: 100%;
//      height: 100%;
//  }
//  &:after {
//      content: '';
//      position: absolute;
//      bottom: 0;
//      right: 0;
//      width: 10px;
//      height: 10px;
//      border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
//      border-right: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
//      transition: 0.5s; 
//  }
//  &:hover:after {
//      width: 100%;
//      height: 100%;
//  }
// `

export const HeroButton2 = styled(Button)`
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 2.75vw, 1.75rem);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
    text-decoration:none;
    background: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: none;
    position: realtive;
    &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, .25);
        color: white;
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
}
`;
```

Hero.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Container, MainHeading } from '../../globalStyles';
import { HeroSection, HeroText, ButtonWrapper, HeroButton1, HeroHeading, HeroButton2 } from './HeroStyles';

const Hero = () => {
    return (
        <HeroSection>
            <Container>
                <HeroHeading>Title</HeroHeading>
                <HeroText>
                    Subtitle
                </HeroText>
                <ButtonWrapper>
                    <Link to="signup">
                        <HeroButton1>Get Started</HeroButton1>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="whitepaper"> 
                        <HeroButton2>Learn More</HeroButton2>
                    </Link>
                </ButtonWrapper>
            </Container>
        </HeroSection>
    );
};

export default Hero;
```

The buttons in question are HeroButton1 and HeroButton2. I commented out the code for HeroButton1 that I want the button to look like. Thanks for your help!